# BQ Aquaris E5 Wifi/3G Issues

Tags: ubuntu-touch, aquaris, bq

I am using E5 in USA and my router has two SSID, with lower and higher Ghz differences. E5 Aquaris is not detecting the high frequency bandwith, why? how do i solve it? Also i could not get connected to my 3G either. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Same here. I noticed it didn't find my 5Ghz SSID when I set mine up also...and now finally checked why.

The phone's connectivity specs:

- **3G HSPA+ (900/2100)** - (B8/B1)
- 2G GSM (850/900/1800/1900)
- **Wi-Fi 802.11 b/g/n**
- Bluetooth® 4.0
- GPS y A-GPS

(Had to get that from: http://www.bq.com/es/aquaris-e5-ubuntu-edition.  Last week the UK link worked; bq must have changed their site.)

Looks like the phone is only `Wi-Fi 802.11 b/g/n` (and maybe only the 2.4 Ghz flavor `n`).  The 5Ghz in your router is likely `a` or `ac`, which isn't listed. (I found the IEEE 802.11 info on Wikipedia. That link didn't make the cut, since I can't post more than 2.)

I haven't tried putting in a sim card, but I don't think the technology and bands for 3G HSPA+ match the GSM carriers in the US.

> In North America, GSM operates on the primary mobile communication bands 850 MHz and 1900 MHz.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_frequency_bands#Americas

Of course, it depends on your carrier and location.